# Change onBackPressed from Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, overriding, back

Currently working on an application with Fragments, I did some Override over the onBackPressed() method in my FragmentActivity. ( I did not incluse the super.onBackPressed willingly so the app won't close)  : 
`@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }`

But now in the fragment I am currently working on, there is a ProgressBar and a Download, so when the Back button is pressed, and the popBackStack() method called, the app just craches.

Is there any possible way to Override the onBackPressed method from a Fragment, or anything I could do about this?

Here is the log :

```
07-01 14:53:16.343: E/AndroidRuntime(14722): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1857
07-01 14:53:16.343: E/AndroidRuntime(14722): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-01 14:53:16.343: E/AndroidRuntime(14722):    at com.example.yourApp.Fragments.FragmentApps$2.run(FragmentApps.java:186)
07-01 14:53:16.343: E/AndroidRuntime(14722):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Help much appreciated

///////////////////

Nevermind, I ended up finding a solution by myself. 
I finally got an idea. 
I'm now using a boolean from the SharedPreferences (instead of from the FragmentApps itself) so it became global and I can use it in both the FragmentActivity and the Fragment.

Comment: what is line FragmentApps.java:186?

Comment: `getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {@Override
public void run() {      bar.setProgress((int) dl_progress);        if (dl_progress == 100) {    barProgressing = false; enableHome(); } } });`